# Подключение django к tcp серверу

Tags: java, python, django, tcp

Как подключить `django` к `tcp` серверу (написан на `java`)?

На сервер поступают разные данные, которые должны посылаться в django, и выводиться в браузере.

Comment: Если чистый tcp без следования какому-либо стандартному протоколу, то в сторону модуля socket копать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: сервер java писал на сокетах то есть чтобы передать в django нужно подключиться как клиент ? и от других клиентов перенаправлять все в django я правильно понимаю?